# Trying to make several raspberries communicate

Tags: python, networking, server, raspberry-pi

I am new to raspberries and networking, but I'm trying to make 3 or 4 raspberries communicate over a (local?) network. They are all located in the same room. I'm thinking of making one of the raspberries host computer and have the other raspberries send data to said host. How would I go about it and where to start? I'm planning to send images and/or text files. I would prefer to use python for coding.

I tried to get started just to send something with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6kuHMY5pHM, but it seems not to work for me.

Comment: Are all PIs connected to a switch? something that will distribute IPs (via DHCP?).
Start by getting them all on the same wired/wifi network (e.g. with Internet access), then find their IPs, and make sure they can all `ping` one-another. Once you have this, you can start thinking at higher-order tasks.

Comment: Yes I can make them ping one-another.

Comment: Great! What kinds of data would you like to send between them?

Comment: I would like to send text files and images, nothing more complicated. Sorry for late answer

Comment: A much simpler way would be to use `scp` for that (assuming your Pis have `ssh` enabled). If you're in an academic exercise, this may be relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/775515/10761353